# What is the meaning of "OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I use Apache Spark 2.4.1 and [kafka data source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html).

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
  .readStream()
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", SERVERS)
  .option("subscribe", TOPIC) 
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("auto.offset.reset", "earliest") 
  .load();
```

I have two sinks: raw data stored in hdfs location , after few transformations final data is stored in Cassandra table. The `checkpointLocation` is an HDFS directory.

When starting the streaming query it gives the warning below:

> 2019-12-10 08:20:38,926 [Executor task launch worker for task 639]
>   WARN  org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer - Some data
>   may be lost. Recovering from the earliest offset: 470021 2019-12-10
>   08:20:38,926 [Executor task launch worker for task 639] WARN 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer - The current
>   available offset range is AvailableOffsetRange(470021,470021).  Offset
>   62687 is out of range, and records in [62687, 62727) will be  skipped
>   (GroupId:
>   spark-kafka-source-1fba9e33-165f-42b4-a220-6697072f7172-1781964857-executor,
>   TopicPartition: INBOUND-19). Some data may have been lost because they
>   are not available in Kafka any more; either the  data was aged out by
>   Kafka or the topic may have been deleted before all the data in the 
>   topic was processed. If you want your streaming query to fail on such
>   cases, set the source  option "failOnDataLoss" to "true".

I also used `auto.offset.reset` as `latest` and `startingOffsets` as `latest`.

> 2019-12-11 08:33:37,496 [Executor task launch worker for task 1059] WARN  org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer - KafkaConsumer cache hitting max capacity of 64, removing consumer for CacheKey(spark-kafka-source-93ee3689-79f9-42e8-b1ee-e856570205ae-1923743483-executor,_INBOUND-19)

What is this telling me? How to get rid of the warning (if possible)?

Comment: Can you include the code for the sinks? They're two different streaming queries BTW. Do the two queries give the warning?

Answer (score 4):

> Some data may be lost. Recovering from the earliest offset: 470021

The above warning happens when your streaming query started with checkpointed offsets that are past what's currently available in topics.

In other words, the streaming query uses `checkpointLocation` with state that is no longer current and hence the warning (not error).

That means that your query is too slow compared to [cleanup.policy](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) (retention or [compaction](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#compaction)).

Comment: @BdEngineer Well, in such case you should simply make your stream processing faster (perhaps by increasing the trigger / batch interval) or change log retention of the Kafka cluster. I gave you the meaning of the warning that should help you take next steps.